# Improve my PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need your help to improve my PHP code. Some years ago (3-4) I created a simple website for a school project. Today I have to create a similar website for personal use. I tried to start from my previous one but I see that a lot of things are not the same.

MySQL_ became obsolete and there is MYSQLI_ or PDO to replace that. I'm trying to do that but it's not very simple for me.

For example I have this code:

```
//connect
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")
    or die ("Pas de connexion au serveur");
//select DB
      $ok = mysqli_select_db($link, cooper)
    or die ("db introuvable");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblComputer";
$rs= mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die ("Erreur de requête : $sql");

print "<div id='tblpos'>";
    print "<table BORDER>";
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
        extract ($row);
```

Could you please tell me if I can continue to use this kind of code? Is `<?php ?>` always good? Previously I was using an include for my connection to the server.

I have also an error telling me "Use of undefined constant cooper - assumed 'cooper' in ... 
(cooper is my DB name and it seem to work because I have the right value on my page.

Comment: `cooper` needs to be in double or single quotes as it's a string

Comment: is that just a typo? or you just forgot that cooper must be enclosed on a single/double qoutes.

Comment: It's worth learning about parameterisation too. This code is safe, but if you need to add values to your SQL that come from the user (e.g. in a `WHERE` clause), have a look at query binding.

Answer (score 1):

For simple personal projects code style is not so important. However, if you want to share your code, or build on it, it's best to use some guidelines, like:

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2

As to to way you connect to the database: it will do the job, but it's not nice. You could start by putting it in a seperate PHP file, so all your other PHP files can share that bit of code by including it.

Propper error handling would be nice. And why not go full out with PDO and use classes?

But again, this is only useful if your project warrants it.